# Facebook Graph API - Post on Group wall as Group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to Facebook Group Wall via Graph API. When i make the post, owner of the post is set as my personal id. Would someone know how to make Group has the owner of the post. Below is my current code:

```
form_fields = {
        "message": 'This is message title',
        "link": 'http://facebook.com',
        "name": 'This is message title',
        "access_token": 'token here'
    }
form_fields['description'] = 'This is message body'
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_fields)
response = urlfetch.fetch(  url="https://graph.facebook.com/%s/feed" % group_id,
                                    payload=form_data,
                                    method=urlfetch.POST,
                                    deadline=10
                                )
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do it. That's one of the differences between the group and pages, in a page when you do a post as an admin the user of the post is the page and not your userid, so there is no way that you can make a group to be the owner of a post using the Graph api. See this link http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=904 and search the question "How are Pages different from Groups?".